# What is 'external data' in Database.deleteAsync(sobject) salesforce documentation

Tags: apex, database

While going through the **Database Class** documents I couldn't understand few definition.

```
deleteAsync(sobject)

Initiates a request to delete the external data that corresponds to the 
specified external object record. The request is executed asynchronously,
as a background operation, and is sent to the external system that's defined by
the external object's associated external data source.
```

What are they trying to refer as: 
***External Data*** , ***external system***

It would be great if someone can point me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External data here refers to the External Objects . External Objects are those that don't reside inside Salesforce system and instead reside outside SFDC while SFDC just stores there metadata definitions .

Any HTTP request can be converted into external objects in salesforce .Odata 4.0 and Odata 2.0 can also be converted into external objects .

[Here is a Trailhead module on the same](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_setup) .The module teaches how to set up a simple external salesforce object from the external data source

Deleteasync will allow you to delete data or remove a row from the external system via an outbound call from the SFDC .

Comment: Thank a lot for pointing the trailhead link @mohit. I ll go through it and mark your ans.